# Chart.js options and documentation

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am wanting to make some slight alterations to my chart but struggling to understand the manual. they are basic alterations I just want to know if anyone has had similar requests or issues as I have looked all over the web but there isn't much out there.

I simply want to change where the key is for my chart and have control over its layout and retain its clickable functions, I did find a little snippet that allowed me to move it but its was just plain text.

My chart

[Chart illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVDuB.png)

Here are the options:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1");
var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx, {

  type: 'radar',
  animationEasing: 'linear',
    options: {
         legend: {
            display: true,            
        },
         tooltips: {
            enabled: true
        },
        scale: {
            ticks: {
                fontSize: 15,
                beginAtZero: true,
                stepSize: 1
            }
        }        
    },
```

Comment: By "key" do you mean "legend"?  What exactly do you want to do to it?  You can place it on the bottom of the chart pretty easily with `position: 'bottom'`

Comment: Sorry yes to correct term would be `legend`, I would like to understand how to control the position of where it is. So but placing `position: 'bottom'` into the option that should move it?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter - so that works great, now if I apply the same to be set to `right` is make the chart tiny and the legend almost like a display block

Comment: Try playing with the width and height parameters to make it wide enough if you want the legend on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration), this will change the position of the legend:

```
options: {
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom'
  }
}
```

> Position of the legend. Possible values are 'top', 'left', 'bottom' and 'right'.

Comment: Where do you see that? I can see other options but not position under Legend, im not disputing that it works but just curious as to where your seeing this in the docs?

Comment: I linked it in the question: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration.  It's the 2nd parameter listed

Comment: What's really strange is that its only position that seems to be taking effect, the other options don't do anything?

Comment: The given link chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration now redirects to http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/.  The page https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html has the information @WillardSolutions originally referenced.